# Why does the file created as a result of the golang application not appear after launching using docker?

Tags: docker, go

I have an application that creates a file, writes something there and completes:
simple example

```
output, err := os.Create("result.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(output)
    writer.WriteString("abc")
    writer.Flush()
    output.Close()
```

and I want to now run this using docker and pass the file name as a parameter.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.19.3-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -o myprogram

VOLUME ["/app/output"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/myprogram"]
```

Start:

```
docker build -t my_app .
docker run my_app test.txt
```

The program works fine, but as a result, the file is not created.What's wrong?

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but could you check the errors on the Close, Flush and WriteString functions?

Comment: Also, how does your Docker image work, does it even have persistent storage? Or is it reset every time it runs? Maybe check your setup there.

Comment: Another thing I can think of is, how do you check your file? Maybe the Go program runs in a different directory than you think and thus it writes the file to some other path. What is your current working directory? E.g. you run your program as user "aaron" but you expected it to be run as user "byron", so you look in the wrong home directory.

Comment: @gonutz I have errors checked , there are none.the file is created in the directory where the program is launched

Comment: how did you determine that the file is not created?

Comment: @Alpharius it won't be retained unless it's written in `/app/output`.

Comment: @Turing85 nothing appears in the directory from where it is launched

Comment: What do you mean with "*the directory from where it is launched*"? Do you mean the directory on the host?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes , where does the dockerfile lie , I want a work file to appear

Comment: This is not how docker works. If we want that the container has access to the host directory, we need a [bind mount (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/): `docker run ... --volume .:/app/outpput ...`. We would also need to rewrite the application to writ to `output` (it currently writes into the `WORKDIR`).

Comment: @Turing85 yes, I looped the program at the end and looked at docker.The desired file appears inside app/output.But how do I make it appear on my computer in the same place where the program is launched and not app/output?I will be glad if you tell me

Comment: `docker run ... --volume .:/app/output ...`

Comment: @Turing85 yes , added but no files appear

Comment: "*We would also need to rewrite the application to write to output (it currently writes into the `WORKDIR`)*"

Comment: @Turing85 I did so ```WORKDIR /app``` ```VOLUME ["/app/result"]``` and in program ```output          string = "./result/result.txt"``` . Where the program with dockerfile lies, I created the result folder.But the file appears inside the container in app/result, but is not created on the computer

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the file is created in a separate directory, it would be better to modify the first line of the code to specify the output directory.

By changing

`output, err := os.Create("result.txt")`

to

`output, err := os.Create("output/result.txt")`

the file will be created in the output directory within the container.

Regarding the Dockerfile, the `VOLUME` instruction is not necessary for this scenario. Instead, you need to specify a volume mount when running the Docker container. Therefore, you can simplify the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM golang:1.19.3-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -o myprogram

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/myprogram"]
```

After updating the Dockerfile, you can build the Docker image using the command:

```
docker build -t my_app .
```

When running the Docker container, you need to mount a volume to the `/app/output` directory. This can be done with the `-v` flag, specifying the local directory to mount to the container's `/app/output` directory. The command would be:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/app/output my_app
```

By using the `-v` flag and specifying the volume mount, the output generated by the program will be written to the local `output` directory.

These changes ensure that the file is created within the `output` directory and that the generated output is properly saved outside the Docker container.

Please note that when running the Docker container, make sure you are executing the command from the same directory where your Go application and Dockerfile are located.